# Total number of contacts - android

Tags: android

I am new to android programming, so excuse me if this is a simple question. How can I get the total number of contacts from the address book?

Answer (score 0):

For Total Count of Contact use below code.

```
Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

int count = cursor.getCount();
```